# EJS Scripts and Stylesheets sections

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm new to node, express, and EJS, coming from ASP.NET MVC. In Razor, there is a feature called "sections" that allows me to specify a placeholder in my layout file for things like scripts and stylesheets, and reference them later in my individual views when those views need particular scripts and stylesheets. That way, all the stylesheets stay at the top, and all the scripts stay at the bottom. Is there a similar feature in EJS?

Comment: EJS is a fairly 'bare metal' implementation although it does have partials, I don't think it would cleanly give you what you want as it's not really modeled on a 'layout' concept. You might want to consider looking at Jade as a template engine. It is the default template engine for Express, which you will probably be using shortly if you aren't already. See the [Github page for Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) - the tutorials it links to on that page are arguably better doc than the official doc at jade-lang.com (whihch is also linked there).

Comment: Thanks, @barry-johnson! If you want, post that comment as an answer and I'll accept it so you get credit.

Comment: No blocks in EJS but here is a simulation of blocks!  https://github.com/dheeraj-br/ejs_layout_implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as answer at your suggestion.

EJS is a fairly 'bare metal' implementation although it does have partials, I don't think it would cleanly give you what you want as it's not really modeled on a 'layout' concept. You might want to consider looking at Jade as a template engine. It is the default template engine for [Express](http://expressjs.com/), which you will probably be using shortly if you aren't already.

Personally, I have found I really like Jade in general. It is much easier on my eyes simply because it is so terse/concise.

Resources:

- [Jade on Github](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade)
- [Jade-lang.com](http://jade-lang.com/)
- [CSS Deck Jade Tutorial - Syntax](http://cssdeck.com/labs/learning-the-jade-templating-engine-syntax)
- [CSS Deck Jade Tutorial - Logic](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jade-templating-tutorial-codecast-part-2)

The use of the `block` syntax is what I think you want for what you describe, and I don't think it is well documented in those resources, but here's an example:

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title #{title} / #{version}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/site.css')
    script(src='/js/mygenericscript.js')
    block head

    body(class='foo')
        // the line below could be written as '#maincontent.bodyclass'
        div(id='maincontent', class='bodyclass')
          block content
```

**template.jade**

```
extends layout

block head
  // here I am including a page-specific script & stylesheet in the head section
  script(src='/js/mypagescript.js')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/crazypage.css')

block content
  div(class='page-specific-class')
    //etc, etc
```

Comment: Perfect! I think the block feature is exactly what I'm looking for. I think I'll end up switching to Jade after I'm done with this throwaway project. And you're right, I didn't see blocks in the official Jade docs.

Comment: What about https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals or https://github.com/Soarez/express-ejs-layouts? Are these viable options for ejs in the OP's scenario? I think you answered the question well, but the question about ejs was not *directly* addressed.

Comment: @mg1075 I agree it was not directly responsive, and had first posted as a comment. Reposted as an answer when asked by the OP. Both libs you appear to be unmaintained. I see a [new EJS 2](https://github.com/mde/ejs), you could see what they are doing with it. Low follower count though and unless a lib has a unique/compelling aspect to it for me, I'll usually choose something that is more broadly used than narrowly used. It doesn't have to be the most popular/used by any means, but something active enough to have a good future. If you have legacy EJS you're supporting, I'd check out 2.0 first.

Comment: @barry-johnson - thanks for the insight. Hey, nunjucks looks like a pretty viable option. Have you played around with it at all? http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#block

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was a viable ejs solution, but based on @barry-johnson's answer it looks like there is not. What is nice (from my perspective) about ejs is how you can still write normal html in your code, but I struggle to see the benefit in yet another abstraction with jade.

This is a big concern, must have for me, and if ejs cannot do the trick well, then ejs does not look to be worth it.

Going with @barry-johnson's comment to look for an alternative, maybe a truly viable option is **[nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/)**. It seems to be an active project, has over a thousand stars on github, and the [block](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#block) option seems to be the answer, although I have not tried anything out yet. (Maybe somebody who already has can confirm.)

http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#block

> **block**
>
> block defines a section on the template and identifies it with a name.
>   This is used by template inheritance. Base templates can specify
>   blocks and child templates can override them with new content. See
>   Template Inheritance.
>
> ```
> {% block css %}
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
> {% endblock }
> ```

Nunjucks uses `{{ }}` syntax in parts, which should be a concern if you are also using AngularJS. However, as was pointed out to me on github, you can get around this issue by customizing the nunjucks syntax, which I believe is preferable to changing Angular's binding syntax.

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#customizing-syntax

Comment: FWIW, some people really don't care for jade. I think the way it treats whitespace is an issue, and also one's feelings about line width. Setting aside the mechanics of it, I also think a big factor on one's opinion is on how repetitive versus how unique the layouts one is creating with it are. For repetitive stuff - e.g. forms & tables for a CRUD interface - I find it very nice. For more complex and irregular layout concepts, it can sometimes add more complexity to working out a good layout. Nunjucks looks pretty well-supported, I may check it out the next time I am starting something.