# Custom Javascript in EJS templates using Sails.js

Tags: javascript, dom, sails.js, ejs

I'm getting wet with Sail.js, which I love so far, but I'm stuck on a simple question: If I have a javascript function that I want to run just on a particular view, where do I invoke it?

A very simple example would be this:

```
  //contact.ejs
  <div id="contact"></div>
  <script>
  renderContact();
  </script>
```

Let's assume `renderContact` is defined in my master JS file for the site, and does what it sounds like: Creates a contact list in `<div id='contact'></div>`.

Of course, that master JS file, as well as all vendor JS, doesn't get loaded until AFTER this script tag since it's injected into `layout.ejs`, so that function will be undefined. I could always natively wait for the page to load like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    renderContact();
});
```

But that seems like a horrible solution.

I realize that Sails integrates powerfully with Angular, React, and so forth, but I first want to understand the basic way that one invokes JS to a single page before I get fancy. There must be a better way to run certain functions only on certain pages once the DOM has loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for `renderContact` to work it should look like this:

```
 <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      HTML
      <script src="master.js"></script>
      <script>
         (function() {
            renderContact();
         })();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The downside of ejs is that AFAIK it does not support blocks. It's kind of bare metal. So you have to put all your scripts in the main layout file and the scripts will be around on pages where they are not needed. But you can configure other template engines in sails, like jade. Jade supports blocks which you can override or extend. Here is an example of jade blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22748166/401025

Comment: Thanks! Switching to SWIG